# How to solve username issue after installing adminlte

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

I installed a  jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE
 which is, Package version 2.x (Laravel 6).After installing i modify my user table, register.blade.php and registercontroller for username and role. But when i submitting the form it always give me a error default value is not set for username.
Here is my view

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('role') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                    <select name="role" class="form-control">
                        <option>Register As</option>
                        <option value="candidate">Candidate</option>
                        <option value="voter">Voter</option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-role form-control-feedback"></span>
                    @if ($errors->has('role'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('role') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
 <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('username') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="{{ old('username') }}"
                           >
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                    @if ($errors->has('username'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
```

And my registercontroller

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'username' => ['required', 'string'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
            'role' => ['required'],
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'role' => $data['role'],
        ]);
    }
```

After modify when i submit i always get this error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'username' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Tanvir, tahmedhera@gmail.com,
>   $2y$10$5XxgDoe272G0wkrcpQYmLepTCGPTPzASBkzXxJ84EhZqOEBvy4zFS,
>   2019-10-25 10:54:25, 2019-10-25 10:54:25))  Please can somebody help
>   me why i getting this error

Comment: yes i am using laravel efault registration form and i added username and role in create method. please see my post

Comment: and where i found the store method

Comment: you need to add `username` in `user.php`  `protected $fillable = ['username'];`

Comment: ohh shitt man how can i forget this. BTW thank you

Comment: no worries.please accpet my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your model, i think username parameter is missing.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'username', 'role'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your model `User.php` you need to add `username` in `$fillable`

Your Model `User.php` should be like:

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'role', 'username
    ];
```

Thanks.